# How can I vertically center a div element

Tags: html, css

I want to center a div vertically with CSS. I don't want tables or JavaScript, but only pure CSS. I found some solutions, but all of them are missing Internet Explorer 6 support.

Comment: Maybe this? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056554/center-horizontally-and-vertically-of-page-ie-6

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in multiple ways. I'll start with grid because I love grid.
CSS Grid Layout excels at dividing a page into major regions or defining the relationship in terms of size, position, and layer, between parts of a control built from HTML primitives.
Grid layout enables an author to align elements into columns and rows.
If you want all the elements contained in an element to be vertically centered you can use on the parent element the property `display: grid;` and after the property `align-items: center;`. For example see this code:

```css
section {
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    display: grid;
    align-items: center;
}

div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<section>
     <div></div>
 </section>
```

if you want a specific alignment for each element, you can avoid specifying the property `align-items: center;` for the parent element and use the property `align-self: center;` directly on each element it contains. See this example:

```css
section {
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    display: grid;
}

div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: brown;
    align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<section>
        <div></div>
</section>
```

another way is through the use of flexbox. The principle is more or less the same.
you can apply a rule that applies to all contained elements:

```css
section {
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<section>
        <div></div>
 </section>
```

or specify the position of each:

```css
section {
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    display: flex;
}

div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: brown;
    align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<section>
        <div></div>
</section>
```

If you want to learn more about these topics I leave you the link of the site from which I learned them: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn

I hope I have been helpful!